# How do I clear the state of a dag run with the CLI in airflow/composer?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

I thought I could use the command:

```
g beta composer environments run <env> --location=us-central1 clear -- <dag_id> -s 2018-05-13 -e 2018-05-14
```

the clear the state of the dag runs on 2018-05-13. For some reason it doesn't work. What happens is that the CLI hangs on a message like:

```
kubeconfig entry generated for <kube node name>.
```

What is the expected behavior of the command above? I would expect it to clear the dag run for the interval, but I might be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Running `clear` on Cloud Composer requires you to add `-c` parameter to the command like so:

`g beta composer environments run <env> --location=us-central1 clear -- <dag_id> -c -s 2018-05-13 -e 2018-05-14`

Comment: Interesting, where is the -c documented?

Comment: https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#Named%20Arguments_repeat3
-c stands for "no confirm"

Comment: This is the correct answer. Without `-c` the command prompts "Are you sure? (yes/no):" without it being visible.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of the command you wrote is the same as running `airflow clear` on a local installation. Maybe the command is just running slow? Are you able to observe any changes to the task instances displayed in the Airflow web UI?

Comment: Then it has to run really slow, didn't observe any changes in the UI. Not even when I "cherry picked" one single date to clear.

Comment: Is the backfill command waiting for the actual backfill to finish or does it just kick of the backfill?

Comment: Have the same issue with version composer-1-6-1-airflow-1-10-1-0ff3124e. Any workaround?

Comment: You can set poke_interval = 0

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
gcloud composer environments run instance-id --location us-central clear -- -s 2018-05-13 -e 2018-05-14 -dx DagID
```

where **-dx** will find all the dags with similar names to your dag, 
and **-c** will run the command without waiting your confirmation.