# Clear cloud composer all Successful dag run states

Tags: google-cloud-composer

I've read [a question on clearing DAG run states in Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50613766/how-do-i-clear-the-state-of-a-dag-run-with-the-cli-in-airflow-composer) but its not obvious,
How I can clear all the DAG run states **including those which are Successful**?
*i.e. I have a backfill job which I would like to start from scratch.*

I also read the [Airflow `clear` CLI Docs](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#clear), it doesn't seem to show how I can only select **Successful** ones too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out, you need to add the `--upstream` and `--downstream` parts into the command in `gcloud`, and then it'll clear the task states too. For example:

gcloud composer environments run jido --location=asia-northeast1 clear -- --dag_regex '*val*' -c -s 2018-12-31 -e 2020-01-01 --upstream --downstream

```sh
$ gcloud composer environments run <environment> \
    --location=asia-northeast1 clear -- <DAG_ID> \
      -c \
      -s <dag run start date> \
      -e <dag run end date> \
      --upstream \
      --downstream
```

Example with fields filled in:

```sh
$ gcloud composer environments run mycomposerenvironment \
    --location=asia-northeast1 clear -- my_important_dag \
      -c \
      -s 2019-08-20 \
      -e 2019-08-31 \
      --upstream \
      --downstream
```

You can also use `dag_regex` which is very useful if you have dynamic dags:

```sh
$ gcloud composer environments run mycomposerenvironment \
    --location=asia-northeast1 clear -- --dag_regex '_val_' \
      -c \
      -s 2019-08-20 \
      -e 2019-08-31 \
      --upstream \
      --downstream
```